# 2 column table with rowspan = 2 and aspect ratio 1/1

Tags: html, css, html-table, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to achieve this result:

[image: Expected result]

But I got this instead:

[image: Current result]

```html
<table class="table" style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; aspect-ratio: 1/2;">
      </td>
      <td style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; aspect-ratio: 1/1;">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; aspect-ratio: 1/1;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve a 1/1 table with rowspan = 2?
My search showed that rowspan and inline-block do not play nicely with each other.
But no fix/alternative was suggested.

Comment: You can not mess with the `display` of table elements like that, making the table cells `inline-block`, and expect the whole thing to still _act_ like a table.

Comment: Put a `div` container into each cell, and apply the `aspect-ratio` to those.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the two square cells aspect-ratio: 1 and display: block then then the rowspan=2 will pick up the correct height without having to specify it.

```html
<table class="table" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; box-sizing: border-box;border-collapse: collapse">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" style="border-right: 1px solid black;">
      </td>
      <td style="display: block; aspect-ratio: 1;">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: block; aspect-ratio: 1; border-top: 1px solid black;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not achieve the expected result. I need the square to take exactly half the width of the table. The rectangle should also take half the width of the table and have an aspect ratio of 1/2.

Comment: The problem with my original suggestion was in-built browser stylings such as margins/padding. I don't know exactly what you want to do about those but have changed the snippet to simply have borders to give the result depicted in your question. Obviously you'll want to set margins etc as you require.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table" style='width: 100%; border: 2px solid orange;'>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" style="width: 50%; aspect-ratio: 1/2; border: 2px solid black;">
                11
            </td>
            <td style="width: 50%; aspect-ratio: 1/1; border: 2px solid red;">
                11
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%; aspect-ratio: 1/1; border: 2px solid green;">
                11
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have removed inline block as it was keeping the layout in inline.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not achieve the expected result. As the table and the squares no longer have an aspect ratio of 1/1. Also, the rectangle needs an aspect ratio of 1/2. Please see the image in my question of the expected result.